# Get menu to print again after selecting a menu option.."do while" loop is infinite after selecting option

Tags: c, loops, menu, printf, do-while

I would like to have the menu print again after the user selects "VIEW" or "BID"..how would I do that without having an infinite loop?? I set up my menu as its own function then called it in my "main" function.

```
    int menu() {
    char sel[6];

    printf("Welcome to the Silent Auction!\n");
    printf("Please make a selection from the following:\n");
    printf("View Auction [VIEW]\n");
    printf("Bid on Auction [BID]\n");
    printf("Close Auction [CLOSE]\n");

return;
    }


    menu();
    char sel[6];
    scanf("%s", &sel);

    do {

            if (strcmp("VIEW", sel) == 0) {
            ...
            }
        if (strcmp("BID", sel) == 0) {
            printf("Which auction would you like to bid on?\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            if ...
    }       else {
                ...
        }    printf("How much would you like to bid?\n");
            scanf("%f", &user_bid);
            if ...
            else
                cur_bid[choice] += user_bid;
            }
        if (strcmp("CLOSE", sel) == 0) {
            for...
        }

        } while (sel != "CLOSE");




    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, there are 2 points to be considered. One, `menu` function needn't return an `int`, but could be a `void` i.e. `void  menu() {`. Since you are not reading the selection inside this function, `char sel[6]` is redundant.

Next, to achieve your objective, before the `while` statement, you can invoke the next call to `menu` as shown below

```
int     close_flag = 0;

printf("Enter your choice, VIEW / BID / CLOSE\n");
scanf("%6s", sel);

printf("Entered Choice: %s\n", sel);

do {
    if(!strcmp(sel, "VIEW"))
    {
        printf("ENTERED VIEW\n");
    }
    if(!strcmp(sel, "BID"))
    {
        printf("BIDDING\n");
    }
    if(!strcmp(sel, "CLOSE"))
    {
        printf(">>>>CLOSING \n");
        close_flag = 1;
    }
    if(!close_flag)
    {
        printf("Enter your choice, VIEW / BID / CLOSE\n");
        scanf("%6s", sel);
        printf("Entered Choice: %s\n", sel);
    }
} while(!close_flag);
```

I have modified the `while` condition to employ a flag to terminate the loop. Also, one further recommendation would be to limit the number of characters of `sel` to **6** characters as shown in `scanf("%6s", sel);`

Comment: that works when the user enters "VIEW" but if they choose another option..say "BID" or "CLOSE", my if statements dont work. it just terminates.

Comment: ok that works for VIEW and BID. But when I select "CLOSE" the program doesnt go thru my if-statement for that..it terminates

Comment: @user2251238 .. please check my updated answer where I use a close flag.

Comment: @user2251238.. please accept the answer if it's working fine as per your expectations..